# Stopping script from changing document.location.href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

A site that I just browsed (cheezburger.com) has apparently vulnerabilities as someone had injected lines like `<script>document.location.href="http://net-cheezburger.cu.cc/"</script>` into messages. Firefox redirected itself to there and X-Frame-Options stopped the framing resulting an empty screen.

Is there other ways to prevent the script from working in Firefox than adding a CAPS policy to document.location.href on cheezburger sites? That blocks legitimate changes too. 
Now I just alert with Greasemonkey that a script is in a wrong place so I know immediately what's going on if they try other malicious scripts.

I'd just like a temporary fix until the site itself is fixed.

I'm wondering is there way to programmatically intercept that script or redirection. If I've understood correctly you can't change inline scripts with Greasemonkey but are there other options?

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with programming.

Comment: not sure that that would really be possible purely with js, anything you could implement in JS could be unimplemented by someone else just as easily... this is where cleaning inserts into the db come into play... strip that stuff out on the way in to the db

Comment: Set a hosts file for `net-cheezburger.cu.cc` to `127.0.0.1`? I'm not sure exactly on what criteria you are deciding to block.

Answer (score 13):

Since you're on firefox (a modern browser), you could use [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to turn the `location` object into read-only:

```
Object.freeze(document.location);

document.location.href = "http://google.com";
// No navigation happens

console.log(document.location.href);
// => "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290948/stopping-script-from-changeing-document-location-href"
```

Comment: That would prevent legitimate uses too which the OP wants to allow.

Comment: On Firefox 64.0 you can't use `Object.freeze`, you get an error `TypeError: can't prevent extensions on this proxy object`.