# Detect it page navigates in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome Extension where I have to click some buttons to trigger an action. This action sometimes results in opening a new page in the same tab. I want to detect this change and navigate back to the same page so that I can continue clicks on remaining buttons.

Is it possible to do using Chrome Extension?
I have gone through webNavigation documentation of Chrome Extension, but didn't find anything there.

I have gone through [Object Freeze Documentation href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290948/stopping-script-from-changing-document-location-href), but that just freezes the document.location.href. The page which I am running Chrome Extension first sends out an AJAX request and checks whether the button click should open a new page, or not.

I just want to click the button and if it navigates, then go back and continue clicking other buttons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping script from changing document.location.href?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290948/stopping-script-from-changing-document-location-href)

Comment: I have edited the question. I don't want to freeze the document location href. I want to freeze the navigation happening by an AJAX request.

Comment: A blocking [webRequest.onBeforeRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) might help.