# Is there any way to prevent `window.location.href` from being changed?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to prevent a mangled & uglified 3rd-party javascript from changing `location.href` *unnecessarily*. `Object.freeze` seems to be a clean and preferable solution, but it does not work :/

The solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290948/stopping-script-from-changing-document-location-href) seems to be ineffective.

```js
Object.freeze(window.location)

window.location.href = 'somewhere'
// still jumped to 'somewhere'... :(
```

An alternative idea is using `beforeunload` event of `window`. But actually I don't think it's a good idea... since it still gives a confirm dialog when the unnecessary jump happens.

I'm currently using Chrome 100 on Windows 10 with `disable-web-security` flag.

Comment: Why not just throw out the mangled 3rd-party script and find something that isn't mangled because that seems to be the root of your problem.

Comment: Ah... I want to, but the script is provided by a captcha platform, which cannot be abandoned if I still want to use their service.

Comment: What do you mean by "*unnecessarily*"? It appears the captcha code considers it necessary to navigate elsewhere. If you don't want that, check with the documentation of customer support of that captcha platform, or find a different captcha provider.

Comment: Sorry for not describing my situation clearly. There is a problem which is already confirmed by its developers. When user clicks the captcha button, I expect it to give a popup so that user can finish the captcha in the popup, which is then closed if finished. However, if `window.open` is not available for some reason, the script will 1. **close the new tab/window** 2. **change `location.href` on current page**, which leads to the missing of filled form values. This is pretty silly.

Comment: The popup window is supposed to exist as user clicks the page. But the script indicates it wrongly, constantly closing the popup. I find a solution to prevent it from closing the tab: by replacing the original `window.open` function to make it always return a valid value (e.g. `window`). *This is not breaking because it is not needed in my codes.* And now I'm stuck in the second step. The developers are not planned to fix this as this might be their weird intension so that they can charge, and they claimed that this problem does not exist in *enterprise version*.